# hibernate collation configure

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I use Hibernate to generate schema and tables. 
It sets the collation to latin1_swedish_ci.

How can I change it to UTF8-general-ci?

application.properties file:

```
#jdbc
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/tutor?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=

# hibernate.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5DBDialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
pool.size=2
#hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourdatabase?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
```

it is `utf8` , not `utf-8`

Comment: `jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/tutor?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8`
added. Still nothing changed. latin1_swedish_ci in the columns

Comment: createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`  --> delete old database schema. use `create-drop` in Hibernate configuration. Let's me know the result.

Comment: I deleted existing schema and then uncomment `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` in the application.properties file but it does not work. 
Am I missing anything when you say "use create-drop in Hibernate configuration"?

Comment: try to re-install your MySQL in your computer. I can create-drop database with UTF-8 ok. Try MySQL version 8 community edition.